How to center a text in its own border using css and html
Before

After

Note:



Using grid and flex




Don't mind the language (Vietnamese)




This is my first time asking for help in Stackoverflow




If you have some "language" problems in the code , please contact below)



I'm having a problem with aligning text in CSS. I want the texts to be in the center of the boxes which have borders outside


body{
  height: 2000px;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    /* background-color: grey; */
    
  }
.img{
 
    filter: brightness(30%);
    
}
header{
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }



  /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

  



h2{
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap:10px;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.box::before {
  content: "Dương Đức Dũng"
  
}
.box{
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  
  
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;

}
h6{
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.thongtin{
  border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
.duan{
  border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
.lilich{
  border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
.chungchi{
    border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
<header>
  <header class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="img"
    width="1247" 
    height="504.67"
    >
      <div class="centered">
        <h1>Dương Đức Dũng</h1>
        <h4>Full Stack Developer</h4>
      </div>
    </header>
</header>
<div class="main-header">
  <h1 class="textname"></h1>
  <nav>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="thongtin">Thông tin</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="lilich">Lý lịch</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <h6>Full Stack Developer</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="chungchi">Chứng chỉ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="">Dự Án</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->
</div>



I've tried lots of methods, but I can't find the solution, I'm a new learner.
I don't know what's happening but when I try to stretch the border, I can't center the text anymore.
I don't know how to describe this problem but I'll give u guys 2 images to compare before and after.
I'm currently stuck in the "before" picture. I want my web to become like the "after" picture.
This is tge nav part of the web.
Hope you guys will help me!

Based on the image that you attached, you can get the result by using Flexbox, I have arranged your code:
HTML:
<body>
  <div class="main-header">
    <nav>
      <div class="box-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <a href="#">Thông tin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <a href="#">Lý lịch</a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper center">
          <h3>Dương Đức Dũng</h3>
          <h6>Full Stack Developer</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <a href="#">Chứng chỉ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <a href="#">Dự Án</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

CSS:
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;

}

.img {
  filter: brightness(30%);

}

nav .box-container {
  height:100px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.wrapper a {
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h6 {
  color: gray;
}


tysm , it works

Happy to hear that and that the solution is working well. Don't forget to mark this answer as the appropriate solution and upvoted.

A good, simple, and direct solution would be just using a flexbox and aligning items to center vertically, using align-items: center; in CSS.
See this example:


body,
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-left: 2px solid skyblue;
  border-right: 2px solid skyblue;
}
<ul>
  <li>Calculus</li>
</ul>




tysm bro , it wworks

Happy learning!

I wrote just the nav part. you should remove the margin of h6 I did it in a class named full-stack. you can use the borders in wrapper class and for wrapper of the centered element use border:0. for same height in flex you can use stretch for align


nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #cecece
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100%
}

.box::before {
  content: "Dương Đức Dũng"
}

.box{
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-right: 0.5px solid red;
  border-left: 0.5px solid red;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.full-stack-wrapper{
  border: 0
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

h6{
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.full-stack{
  margin: 0
}
  <nav>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="thongtin">Thông tin</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="lilich">Lý lịch</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper full-stack-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <h6 class="full-stack">Full Stack Developer</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="chungchi">Chứng chỉ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <div class="box">
        </div> -->
        <a href="#" class="">Dự Án</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>



